# Ansible - AWX (Tower) - How to correctly setup SSH key based connections

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-awx

This is a bit of a loaded question but looking for some guidance and best practices on this question.  Skill level is moderate with Ansible but newbie with AWX.

**Current scenario**:

AWX is being setup, so no real setup yet but basics (inventory, some creds, projects, templates).
In Ansible (how I do this without AWX):

1. 'common_playbook' that 1st time connects via username/password
2. Copies the Ansible host's SSH pub key (separate key created for only
   this purpose) to the target via posix.authorized_key module
3. Modify the target's 'known_host' via known_host module

So this basically allows the Ansible controller to connect to a new target the 1st time via user/pass and then SSH from there on.

**Question**:

- Would/should I deploy the same logic with AWX (especially since it is
  a container)?
- Does AWX handle SSH keys a little different than Ansible (standalone)?
- I know I can add the SSH key into the inventory file but that is not
  recommended either.

**Environment**:

- Ansible controller (standalone): 2.10.8
- AWX: 17.1.0 (sitting in Docker container) with Ansible 2.9.18
  embedded Ansible
- All OS's (Ansible host & AWX host): CentOS7

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/credentials.html#machine

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.  I had looked at this doc but the logic to handle 1st time connections is not addressed.

I don't want to have to add every new server (as these can/will get spun up dynamically).  So the idea is once inventory is updated, Ansible goes and finds the target and starts the 'common' process.

Unless I missed something within this doc.

Comment: Spin up the servers directly with the correct deploy user and public key. Use the same corresponding private key from awx. Alternatively, you can push the public key from awx right after spinup using a login/pass if you know it.